# xml to csv with minidom

Tags: python, xml, minidom

I have a problem with my program and i need some help.
I need my saida.txt with these things:

+, adj, teçste

+, adj, oiaã

+, adv, 123

+, adv, oshi

-, adv, teste1

-, adv, oi1

But im getting only these things in my saida.txt:

```
+, adv, 123 
+, adv, oshi 
-, adv ,teste1
-, adv ,oi1
```

My xml ("pedaco.xml") is:

```
<data>
      <ver>
        <pontuacao>+</pontuacao>
        <nuver>palavra1</nuver>
        <tiver>palavra2</tiver>
        <cl>
         <nocl>adj</nocl>
             <an>teçste</an>
             <an>oiaã</an>
        </cl>
        <cl> 
            <nocl> adv</nocl>
            <an> 123 </an>
            <an> oshi </an>
        </cl>
    </ver>

      <ver>
        <pontuacao>-</pontuacao>
        <nuver>palavra3</nuver>
        <tiver>palavra4</tiver>
        <cl>
         <nocl>adv</nocl>
             <an>teste1</an>
             <an>oi1</an>
        </cl>

      </ver>
     </data>
```

My full code is

```
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*
from xml.dom import minidom
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")
xmldoc = minidom.parse("pedaco.xml")

arquivo = open('saida.txt','w')

ver = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('ver')
for node in ver:
  nuver = node.getElementsByTagName('nuver')
  tiver = node.getElementsByTagName('tiver')

  pontuacao = node.getElementsByTagName('pontuacao')
  cl = node.getElementsByTagName('cl')

  for c in cl:
    an = c.getElementsByTagName('an')
    nocl = c.getElementsByTagName('nocl')


  for a in pontuacao:
    printando1 = a.childNodes[0].nodeValue
    for b in nocl:
      printando2 = b.childNodes[0].nodeValue
      for c in an:      
    printando3 = c.childNodes[0].nodeValue
    arquivo.write(printando1+",")
    arquivo.write(printando2+",")
    arquivo.write(printando3+"\n")
```

Comment: Python has a `csv` module? Have you tried using that?

Comment: Assuming you care about the destination and not the journey, you might also want to [reuse what others have done](http://nadh.in/code/xmlutils.py/).  That link goes to `xmlutils`, written in Python with an MIT license.

Comment: yes i tried, but my the xml that i really need to use is very bigger than pedaco.xml.. and i need only some "tags", i think.. if  i use it i will get everything, but i only want some tags, then i was trying to make my csv. My problem is why im not getting the "adj"..

Comment: Are you getting any errors due to incorrect encoding when parsing the XML file?

Comment: @Marco If you have a big XML *do not use* `minidom`. `ElementTree` (or better yet `cElementTree`) is *much* faster.